# Trouble Uploading Image to Server

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to upload an image from my app to my server. I am following this tutorial (http://zcentric.com/2008/08/29/post-a-uiimage-to-the-web/). When I copy the code from the tutorial I get a bunch of warnings and errors, so I have modified it as below.

The uploadImage method is being called, and twitterImage contains the right photo, but the image is not being uploaded into the user_photos directory. Any recommendations would be great!

**Here is my app code:**

```
-(void)uploadImage {

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(twitterImage, 90);
NSString *urlString = @"http://website.com/user_photo_upload.php";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------673864587263478628734";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; 
    boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rn--%@rn",boundary] 
    dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"userfile\"; 
    filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-streamrnrn" 
    dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rn--%@--rn",boundary] 
    dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
    returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData 
    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

**Here is my user_photo_upload.php file:**

```
<?php

$uploaddir = '../user_photos/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "http://website.com/user_photos/{$file}";
}

?>
```

Comment: First check the service using any REST adon on a web browser as a thub rule

Comment: Hi Amar, would that be a setting on the server?

Comment: its "\r\n--%@\r\n" at every plce try this

Comment: Which one: NSString stringWithFormat:@"rn--%@rn" or NSString stringWithFormat:@"rn--%@--rn"

Comment: replace rn with \r\n put escape char before each occurrence of r and n otherwise they do not qualify as carriage return and new line

Answer (score 0):

In my suggestion, you can use **ASIHTTPRequest** framework for image uploading to the server. You can download the framework from [here](http://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tarball/master). It is simple easily understandable.

See the below code regarding image uploading using ASIHTTPRequest

```
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(IMAGE, 0.9);
formReq = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
formReq.delegate = self;
[formReq setPostValue:VAL1 forKey:KEY1];
if (imgData) {
    [formReq setData:imgData withFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ipodfile.jpg"] andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"userfile"];
}
[formReq startSynchronous];
```

You can also refer a nice tutorial [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

Comment: should discontinue asihttp now its not being maintained

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move from `NSMutableURLRequest` then best bet is `AFNetworking` get it [from here](http://afnetworking.com/)

**`ASIHTTPRequest` is not being maintained and should not be used as said by developer** of [library here](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D)
Example oF image upload

```
 -(void)call
    {
        //the image name is Denise.jpg i have uses image you can youse any file
        //just convert it to nsdat in an appropriateway
        UIImage *image= [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Denise" ofType:@"jpg"]];
        //  getting data from image
        NSData *photoData= UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

        // making AFHttpClient
        AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your url string"]];

        //setting headers
        [client setDefaultHeader:@"multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=0xKhTmLbOuNdArY" value:@"Content-Type"];
        [client setDefaultHeader:@"key" value:@"value"];
         NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"application/uploadfile" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
        //setting body

             [formData appendPartWithFormData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Value"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"Key"];
            [formData appendPartWithFormData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Value"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"Key"];
//...
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:photoData name:@"file_data" fileName:@"file.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
        }];
        [request1 setTimeoutInterval:180];
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request1];
        [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
            NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
            float progress = totalBytesWritten / (float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
        // use this float value to set progress bar.
        }];
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
         {

             NSDictionary *jsons = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];
             NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
             NSLog(@"response headers: %@", [[operation response] allHeaderFields]);
             NSLog(@"response: %@",jsons);

         }
                                         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
         {

             if([operation.response statusCode] == 403)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Upload Failed");
                 return;
             }
             NSLog(@"error: %@", [error debugDescription]);

         }];
        [operation start];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When You are appending the image to body the Content-Disposition should be an **attachment** not **form-data**, just before you are appending the image-data on the body. so replace the following code:

```
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"userfile\"; 
filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

with this:

```
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: attachment;name=\"userfile\"; 
filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```